# Change the Kibana 4 Discover and Visualize Page Themes

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4

I keep my Kibana Dashboard and Discover pages open on two different displays in our NOC. I want the Discover page to have the same "Dark" theme as my dashboard. However, I see that in Kibana 4.5 this is not a clickable option. Does anyone know where in Kibana4's code I can enable this, or can anyone point to a plugin that will enable this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/6786) to enable the dark theme everywhere in Kibana and not just the dashboard.

There are a few ways to achieve what you want. The quickest one is to modify the `optimize/bundles/commons.style.css` file and blatantly copy all `.tab-dashboard.theme-dark` rules to `.tab-discover.theme-dark` and `.tab-visualize.theme-dark` rules.

The correct way of doing it is to checkout the kibana project (`git clone https://github.com/elastic/kibana.git`), then modify the `src/ui/public/styles/dark-theme.less` LESS file to replace

```
.tab-dashboard.theme-dark {
```

by

```
.tab-dashboard.theme-dark, .tab-discover.theme-dark, .tab-visualize.theme-dark {
```

You'll then need to recompile the LESS files to generate a new `commons.style.css` file using `grunt build` and you can replace your current `optimize/bundles/commons.style.css` with the newly generated one.

Enjoy your dark theme!!

Comment: Thank you so much, this makes all the difference. I have all three screens open and embedded in iframes in our NOC, this looks so much better.